# firestore read count with where condition -indexed

Tags: firebase, indexing, google-cloud-firestore, price

firestore documentation pricing didn't mention the read on indexed data with where conditions..

if we have a collection (invoice) with 100K docs with fields like (date, number,amount)

and i did a query get().where('date' , '==', 20180404')
is this will count the 100K or only returned docs?

thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Queries use indexes, they don't read every individual document. You'll get charged based on the number of documents returned, not on the size of the collection.

Also see [Todd's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47146115/firestore-pricing-does-the-amount-of-documents-in-a-collection-matters?rq=1), which I'm actually going to mark your question as a duplicate of.

Comment: thanks for link, i think this should be added to firestore pricing documentation..