# How to handle nested collection query in cloud flutter firestore?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

If have a collection like this

```
Shop(Collection):
     -shopId(Document)
         -name
         -adresse
         -itemSold (Nested Collection)
             -itemId
                 -....
                 -....
```

how can i write a query in flutter that will return me only the shop that have a specific itemId in itemSold collection.

Its this gonna cost many read?

How are you handling that kind of tree on your side i am pretty new in noSQL database. Im use to traditionnal database.

Comment: Hi, If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Firestore query subcollections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46573014/firestore-query-subcollections)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the .where method.

In your case something like this:

```
DocumentReference shopInstance = Firestore.instance
        .collection('shops')
        .document('shopsID'):
await shopInstance
      .collection('itemSold')
      .where('itemID', isEqualTo: 'someId')
      .getDocuments()
      .then()...
```

Comment: Hello Itiel , thanks for the answer! It give me a better idea. Do you know if that kind of setup is good or bad? I think the document will be smaller but it will make more reads count.

Comment: Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47146115/firestore-pricing-does-the-amount-of-documents-in-a-collection-matters